# When assigning an int array to another int array variable, if we perform Arrays.sort on the new array variable, does it affect the original int array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, oop

Here is the code block I am referring:

```
public class ExtraCandies
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] candies = {2,3,5,1,3};

        int temp = 0;
        List<Boolean> isGreatestPossibleList = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] tempArray = candies;

        Arrays.sort(tempArray);

        //Here the debugger shows both tempArray and candies array as sorted.
    }
}
```

When I debug this code, I get that the tempArray gets sorted just fine. And the tempArray becomes {1,2,3,3,5}. But the debugger now also shows the candies array got sorted. I am confused how can this be? Shouldn't the sort method only sort the tempArray here?

Comment: Short answer is Yes.  It does affect the "original" array, because you have copied the array *reference* not the array.

Comment: I have a dup-closed this as a dup of a question that explains what assigning one array variable to another actually does.  What you are seeing is a direct consequence of that.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning an array to another array is not actually duplicating it - you are just setting the reference of the original array to the new one. Sorting the array would mean sorting the reference, thus sorting both arrays.

You'll want to use a `for` loop, or `Arrays.copyOf(array, length)`

```
public class ExtraCandies
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] candies = {2,3,5,1,3};

        int temp = 0;
        List<Boolean> isGreatestPossibleList = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] tempArray = Arrays.copyOf(candies, candies.length);

        Arrays.sort(tempArray);

        //Here the debugger shows both tempArray and candies array as sorted.
    }
}
```